# Installing certbot for nginx on Raspberry Pi 4 gives PackageNotFoundError

Tags: nginx, raspberry-pi, lets-encrypt, certbot

I try to install certbot by executing:
`sudo apt install python3-certbot-nginx`
The install is working fine, it is installing certbot 1.12.0-2 and python3-certbot-nginx 1.12.1-1
I can find 2 executables of `certbot` after the install:

```
(venv) pi@raspberrypi:~/Documents/my_project $ which -a certbot
/usr/bin/certbot
/bin/certbot
```

When I try to execute any of the two, it gives the following error:

```
(venv) pi@raspberrypi:~/Documents/my_project $ certbot --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/certbot", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('certbot==1.12.0', 'console_scripts', 'certbot')())
  File "/usr/bin/certbot", line 22, in importlib_load_entry_point
    for entry_point in distribution(dist_name).entry_points
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/metadata.py", line 524, in distribution
    return Distribution.from_name(distribution_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/metadata.py", line 187, in from_name
    raise PackageNotFoundError(name)
importlib.metadata.PackageNotFoundError: certbot
```

Raspbian version: Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)

How can I solve this error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is solved by installing through `snap` according to the certbot instructions: https://certbot.eff.org/instructions?ws=nginx&os=debianbuster&tab=standard